# int** in c and int[][] in c# is same?

Tags: c#, c

I have a DLL file that is written in C. I am try to use C DLL in my c# code. C program method return int** . int** in c and int[][] in c# is same?

I am getting an error while returning a value from c program.

c method

```
__declspec(dllexport) int someMethod
    (
        size_t *foo, 
        int **bar
    ) 
    { 
        *foo = 10; 
        **bar = 10; 
    }
```

My c# code

```
[DllImport(@"my.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, SetLastError = true, BestFitMapping = true, EntryPoint = "someMethod")]
    public unsafe static extern int someMethod
    (
        out Int16 foo, 
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.CustomMarshaler, MarshalTypeRef = typeof(JaggedArrayMarshaler))] 
        out int[][] bar
    );
```

Comment: Can you show us some of your code? What error are you getting?

Comment: `**` is a pointer to a pointer. `[][]` is an array of arrays, or in other words `jagged`. I have a feeling it doesn't mean the same thing :)

Comment: A simple console app. with the DLLImport statements would help

Comment: Simple answer to your question is no. Since you didn't tell us the problem you are trying to solve, we cannot help much more than that.

Comment: The C# equivalent of int** variable is unsafe { int** variable; }

Comment: Wait, if it's an `out` parameter, then you're probably missing a star.

Comment: My first out parameter working fine, but when issues occur when my c program return some value in second parameter. When second parameter is null then working fine.

Comment: `int **` shout match `int[][]` or `out int[]` for me. If you want an `out int[][]`, you should probably use an `int ***` on the C side.

Answer (score 1):

C's `int**` and C#'s `int[][]` are similar in concept, but different at the binary level:

- `int**` is a pointer to pointer, into the raw data in unmanaged heap memory.
- `int[][]` is a managed reference to a managed array of managed references to managed arrays; each points to the array's header (which contains its length) instead of its raw data.

I don't know what would be easiest to marshal for C#. Can `SAFEARRAY` be nested? If so, it would probably easily map to C# arrays.

The solution that's sure to work is to use a C++/CLI DLL as glue between the two codes, to convert the `int**` into a `cli::array<cli::array<int>^>^` (which involves copying the pointed data) before returning to C#.

Comment: "but different at the binary level" - how so?

Comment: @SecurityMatt I just added the info.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the C function prototype is correct, I think you should declare it thusly on the C# side:

```
public unsafe static extern int someMethod
(
    out Int16 foo, 
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex=0, ArraySubType=UnmanagedType.I2)] 
    out int[] bar
);
```

However, I fear a memory leak. I'm not sure how the unmanaged array can be deallocated.

Comment: System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalDirectiveException: Cannot marshal 'parameter #2': Cannot use SizeParamIndex for ByRef array parameters. I am getting this error.

Comment: This must mean the standard marshaller cannot marchal arrays as out parameters.